# UIWebView and UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, webkit

I have a webview to which is attached a swipe gesture recognizer, and the gesture is picked up correctly.

Now I have an HTML file loaded in the webview with some draggable content (HTML/JQuery). When the content is being dragged, it also triggers the swipe gesture, which I do not want.

**How can I prevent a swipe from being triggered when dragging content around in HTML?**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeRight.delegate = self;
    [_webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];



- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored
{
NSLog("triggered");
}
```

TIA!
S.

Comment: I think you can't. But maybe there's a solution for your original problem. Why do you ant to use your own swipe gesture recognizer on a web view?

Comment: could you detect when the dragging is began ?